# mysql get name by id in select query in multiple records

Tags: mysql

i've stuck in mysql query. i've a employee table whose fields are id, name, bossid and bossid is parent id of employee.

[image]

How i write the query to print the data in this format

```
 id   name     boss
 1    rajesh   rajesh
 2    vijay    rajesh
 3    ravi     vijay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the table with itself:

```
Select t1.id as id 
     , t1.name as Name 
     , t2.name as boss 
  from employee t1 
  join employee t2 
    on t1.bossid = t2.id
```

Comment: @Viju You are welcome. Feel free to upvote and/or accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, name, 
  (SELECT B.name from `users` B WHERE B.id = A.bossid) bossname 
  FROM `users` A
```

Try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddb50/2